# A taylor series for an integral with a singularity

Tags: calculus, analysis, complex-integration

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function with a single root we call $y_*$. Then define

\begin{equation}
F_{\delta}:=\int^{y_*+ \delta/2}_{y_*- \delta/2} 1/f(y)dy
\end{equation}

Let $\delta \ll 1$. Is it possible to write $F_{\delta}$ as a taylor series? By which I mean
\begin{equation}
 A + B \delta + C \delta^2 + \cdots
\end{equation} 
If so, how do I arrive at the expressions for $B,C$ etc. ?

Comment: Yes. Experiment with $y_*=0$, $f=ay+by^2$, then with $f=ay+by^2+cy^3$ to see. You may want to use series expansion for $1/f$. It would lead to some lengthy formulas in general. BTW Here we are assuming $\int dy /y$ on a symmetric region is $0$.

Comment: Series expanding $1/f$ doesn't really work. However, I think you meant that you can generally write $f=g h$ where $g$ contains the roots. Then you can Taylor expand $1/h$ and arrive at some expression.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of singularity.  Let's say that $f(y) \sim (y-y_*)^{a}$ near this singularity.  If $a \lt 1$ then the singularity is integrable and you'll get something like

$$\frac{1}{1-a} \left [(y-y_*)^{1-a}\right]_{y_*-\delta/2}^{y_*+\delta/2}$$

which you will find has some complex part.  If $a \ge 1$, on the other hand, the integral diverges and your proposed expansion is invalid.

You may have something in mind like a Cauchy principal value, in which you consider the limit as $\delta \to 0$, but I am not aware of any meaningful expansion in delta.